# Change value of override variable in a method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a Base fragment with an abstract variable which wants to handle my search in implementation fragments.

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
    abstract var handleSearch : () -> SymbolTypeView?
}
```

I override this value in all fragments like:

```
override var handleSearch: () -> SymbolTypeView? = { SymbolTypeView.Gold }
```

but my **problem** is in a tab. When I load a tab, the next tab is also loaded and I need this loading but the variable which I use the value in MainActivity gets the last loading tab, not the current tab. In addition, I need to force other developers to override this variable. So I should put it in the BaseFragment.I try to change the value in the method but this way doesn't work. Do you have any idea about it?

**Example**: We have two tabs next to each other. I override a variable in the first Tab and set the value to GOLD. Also, I override the second tab variable to COIN. The current tab is Gold and I invoke this variable in MainActivity. So I expect the value to be Gold but I see COIN.

Comment: Share the code how you get the value from fragment inside MainActivity

Comment: (requireActivity() as HomeActivity).handleSearch = handleSearch
I define the same variable there and I use this code to set the value in the MainActivity.